# Click event with DOM dynamically updates

Tags: jquery

I'm playing with a few samples to learn jQuery. I made an example to add items to a list when user clicks an `add` button and display items list when they click in any item of the list:

The code:

HTML

```
<div id="sample"></div>
    <a id="add" href="#">Add</a>
    <ul id="list">
        <li>old item</li>
        <li>old item</li>
        <li>old item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var $itemsList = jQuery('#list li');

jQuery('#add').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#list').append('<li>new item</li>');
    $itemsList = jQuery('#list li');
});

$itemsList.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('there are ' + $itemsList.length + ' items');
    $itemsList.each(function(){
        console.log(jQuery(this).text());
    });
});
```

The problem:

If the user clicks in old items, the console displays all items (old and new), but if the user clicks in new items, created by clicking the `add` button, they are not being displayed. I'm assuming that the event click was asigned to `$itemsList`, and this object only refers to items created when script loads but not with successive created items.

Any advice, sugestions?

Comment: The click line is executed only once, and applies the handler to the element pointed by $itemsList at that moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing this `$itemsList.click(...)` you bind an event handler to the 'click' event, but even if you re-select the list items in the 'Add' event handler, new items are not binded automatically.

You have to use event delegation for you click event to binded to elements added dynamically.

```
$('#list').on('click', 'li', clickHandler);
```

Doing this can be translated into: delegate the 'click' event on the element #list, and restrain the event handling to `li` elements only (second parameter).

The .on() method was added in jquery 1.7. In case you use a prior version of the library, use .delegate().

Note: forget about .live() which is deprecated.

Documentation on [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: In this situation better use live() than delegate.If on() doesn't exists.

Comment: .live() is deprecated, which means it could be removed in any other update of the library, you should not use it anymore.

Comment: thanks, you pushed me on right direction. Using delegate() works correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
var $itemsList = jQuery('#list');

jQuery('#add').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#list').append('<li>new item</li>');
    $itemsList = jQuery('#list li');
});

$itemsList.on("click","li",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('there are ' + $itemsList.length + ' items');
    $itemsList.each(function(){
        console.log(jQuery(this).text());
    });
});
```

jQuery 1.7.1

> ON() -> live() or delegate()

Description: Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are appending new items to the DOM, you need to use a different method to assign them handlers, as `click()` is only used for DOM elements available to jQuery on load.

Instead, use `delegate()` to add the handlers:

```
var $itemsList = jQuery('#list li');

jQuery('#add').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#list').append('<li>new item</li>');
    $itemsList = jQuery('#list li');
});

$("#list").delegate("LI", "click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#total").text('there are ' + $itemsList.length + ' items');
    $itemsList.each(function(){
        console.log(jQuery(this).text());
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/785MG/2/)

Or, if you're using jQuery 1.7+ you can use `on()` instead of `delegate()`, but their functionality essentially the same in this scenario.